# Не получается установить пакеты npm

Tags: node.js, npm

При установки любых пакетов `npm` выдаёт мне ошибку:

> npm ERR! Class constructor LRUCache cannot be invoked without 'new' 
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
>   npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-11T08_36_24_229Z-debug.log

Скажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Тут ничего не поделать, пакет просто поломан. Если вы зайдёте на их github репозиторий в раздел issues, то найдёте там множество открытых проблем с установкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, обновив nodejs до 10 версии. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> npm install peterbraden/node-opencv
> ```

Это какая-то левая команда, на их сайте [инструкция из 5 шагов](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv#specific-for-windows) и команда выглядит так:

```
npm install opencv
```

Comment: Выдает тоже самое.

Comment: @Log1c0, все 5 шагов выполнил? А другие пакеты ставятся?

Comment: У меня linux, другие пакеты не ставятся(

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы установить **npm** пакеты надо проста написать

```
npm i имя пакета
```

или

```
npm install имя пакета
```

В вашем случае для opencv вы должны написать

```
npm i opencv
```

Ссылка на npm [**тут**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv)

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло